# Append image to TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, drawable

I've tried for two day now to append an image to a TextView, but it didn't work. I have tried this for Android 6/API Level 23. ImageSpan, Html.fromHtml and other Methods did not work. So is it possible to append image (Bitmap) between other words in a TextView on Android 6?

---

> EDIT

---

Here is the XML:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="------"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:id="@+id/mainTextView1"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

And image span Code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(mOutEditText.getText()); ssb.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bitmapArray.get(0), ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), cursorPosition, cursorPosition+2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); mOutEditText.setText(ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: can you put your xml/java code that you've tried?

Comment: Here is the XML Code @Sudip Podder

Comment: what's wrong with using a separate imageView at the end of the textView?

Comment: I want to use them as emoticons in the text. @Sudip Pudder

Comment: Look into TextView drawables (such as drawableLeft)

Comment: Then i cannot use it as emoticons

Comment: Emojis should be handled via unicode

Comment: I thought of using an image span but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: No i didn't exactly mean emoticons but... Small images

Comment: Ok thanks i will find sth

Comment: The answer is ImageSpan.  If it didn't work, its because you either want something more than you're saying, or because you made a mistake in your implementation

Comment: Or because it simply doesnt work on api level 23?

Comment: @user6765242 what do you mean? ImageSpan was added in API 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution now for Api 21, 22, 23+:

```
private void appendImage(Bitmap bmp)
{
    tv.setTransformationMethod(null);
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("  ");
    ss.setSpan(new ImageSpan(bmp, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.append(ss);
}
```

And in the XML:

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

The error was that in api level 21+ you have to set the TransformationMethod null.

Answer (score 2):

Add image in xml

```
<TextView
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    android:drawablePadding="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

programmatically

```
textView1.setCompoundDrawables(left,top,right,bottom);
```

Or only left

```
textView1.setCompoundDrawables(left,null,null,null);
```

Comment: Thanks but that wasnt that what i meant

Comment: You can use Webview

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the background of the TextView use the following methods:

```
txt.setBackgroundResource(int rsid);
txt.setBakgroundDrawable(Drawable object);
```

If by append, you mean you want to add it to the end of the TextView, then use an ImageView for the image. Or you can overlay your TextView in an ImageView

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add images between text in a TextView. You can add an image a TextView at the start and end. This is done with

```
android:drawableLeft
```

Comment: Thanks but that wasnt that what i searched

Comment: I answered your question by saying its not possible. And I was just giving a suggestion for another way to add images to a textview

Comment: It's possible - see my answer